# Swift - TipUIPopoverViewController to stay visible even on scroll

Tags: swift, tooltip

I'm playing and trying new things with the new tooltip from TipKit, but it seems that natively the tool is dismiss on scroll or outside tap on the screen. I was wondering if anyone succeed of making it stick until the main view is dismissed or on button action tap. I investigated the UIPopoverViewControllerDelegate but did not successfully made it work. I implemented it in my MainViewController and set my tooltip class popover delegate in it too.

```
class Tooltip {
    var tipPopoverController: TipUIPopoverViewController?

func displayToolTip(_ config: ToolTipCreatorConfig) {
    let popoverController = TipUIPopoverViewController(
        config.toolTip,
        sourceItem: config.sourceItem) { [weak self] _ in
            config.actionHandler()
        }
    popoverController.viewStyle = GenericTipViewStyle()
    popoverController.view.backgroundColor = Asset.Colors.bookmarkToolTipBackground.color
    // Set the passthroughViews property with an array of views that should receive touches
    popoverController.popoverPresentationController?.passthroughViews = config.enabledViewsToBeTouched ?? []

    self.mainViewController.present(popoverController, animated: true)
     }
}

class MainViewController: UIViewController {
    tooltip.displayPopOver(parentVC: self, config: config)  
    tooltip.tipPopoverController?.popoverPresentationController?.delegate = self
}

extension MainViewController: UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {
                override func presentationControllerShouldDismiss(_ presentationController: UIPresentationController) -> Bool {
                    return false
                }
    }
```